# NUCLEO H743ZI-2 CAN FD unreliable

Tags: can, bus

I am writing a library to use the CAN Bus on this STM32 board. Physically this board has CAN FD, which is CAN 2.0 compatible. I require a CAN transceiver to connect to the CAN-H and CAN-L lines.

I am trying to control a motor but the messages are inconsistent. Sometimes they are sent others they are not.

In the same CAN lines I have a USB-CAN to sniff the messages in the line, so I can see that the message sent by the controller is replied by the motor. I can see sometimes the message is sent by the controller but the motor is not replying. Sometimes the message is not read by the USB-CAN and I can see it should be because it is in the code. Other times no error occurs and it behaves at it should but it is unreliable.

Physically the STM32 board (CAN FD port) is connected to a CAN 2.0 transceiver and that transceiver to the CAN H and CAN L lines.

I can rule out that the transceiver is the problem because if I connect it to a teensy 3.6 and send the same messages, the motor replies as it should and runs all the time.

Do you think I need a CAN FD transceiver? Have you experience the same problems of unreliability ?

Comment: Show some schematics, board layout:  STM32 CAN transceiver VS. Teensy CAN Transceiver.

Comment: There are [4 errata related to FDCAN for the STM32H743](https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/dm00368411-stm32h742xig-and-stm32h743xig-device-limitations-stmicroelectronics.pdf). Please check if you applied all the workarounds.

Comment: Here is the schematic https://imgur.com/IkCH704 . I will read the errata , thanks for the info.

Comment: I did not have met any of the errata, I only have one TxFIFO, no activating the TTTs, only one fdcan and no edge filtering

Comment: How these boards are powered?

Comment: All is through USB of the computer